# mostrar un mensaje de Cargando... **AngularJS (Angular 1)**

Tags: javascript, angularjs

tengo una descargar de un documento PDF, actualmente hay veces que tarda en realizar la petición y no se como ver en que estado esta la petición para mostrar un mensaje de carga.

```
function downloadPDF () {
        $log.debug('btn descargar PDF');

        var url = Constants.BaseURLBack + '/mir/reportes/matriz?idMir=' + idMir;
        RestService.getFile(url,'application/pdf')
        .then(function(response) {
            var blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: "application/pdf" });
            saveAs(blob, "matriz.pdf");        
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            message("error","Excel sin datos","Por favor seleccione un proyecto con datos");
            console.log("Error al descargar el excel", err);
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes poner un GIF de loading al lado del botón en tu html:

```
<img ng-if="mostrarCargando" src="imagenes/cargando.gif"/>
```

y le das valores antes y despues de la descarga:

```
function downloadPDF() {
    $log.debug('btn descargar PDF');
    $scope.mostrarCargando = true;

    var url = Constants.BaseURLBack + '/mir/reportes/matriz?idMir=' + idMir;
    RestService.getFile(url, 'application/pdf')
    .then(function (response) {
        var blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: "application/pdf" });
        saveAs(blob, "matriz.pdf");
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        message("error", "Excel sin datos", "Por favor seleccione un proyecto con datos");
        console.log("Error al descargar el excel", err);
    });
    $scope.mostrarCargando = false;
}
```

Comment: lo hice de esa manera el problema que en ocasiones la petición tarda y la imagen o mensaje desaparece pero la petición sigue en curso

Comment: Deberías considerar mover la linea `$scope.mostrarCargando = false;` dentro del `then` y el `catch`.

Comment: De hecho, debería considerar añadir un `.finally()` y dentro de él, cambiar el flag de `$scope.mostrarCargando` a false. Por eso, te pasa que la imagen desaparece mientras la petición sigue pending @wootsbot